# IsoDateTimeConverter ignores my specified date format

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

During serialization, serializer ignores my specified date format and get it from local pc, for example, I specified 'dd/MM/yyyy' and local pc format is 'dd-mmm-yyyy', serializer gets format from pc, can anyone help me? Why it comes from local pc?

bellow are all examples

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var obj = new Request { Id = "1", Language = "en", BirthDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31) };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        }
     }




    public class Request
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "player")]
        public string Id { get; set; } //id

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lang")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "birthdate")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverters.DateTimeConverter), "dd/MM/yyyy")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; } //birthdate
    }

    public class JsonConverters
    {
        public class DateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            public DateTimeConverter(string format)
            {
                DateTimeFormat = format;
            }
        }
    }
```

serialization result is

```
{
 "player": "1",
 "lang":"en",
 "birthdate":"31-12-2012"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The real question is why are you trying to use a non-standard format which is guaranteed to fail on the browser and clients? ISO8601 is the defacto standard for dates in JSON. Anything else is simply text. .NET clients will work with ISO8601 just fine, no matter what the PC's locale is

Comment: If you *remove* the `JsonConverter` attribute you'll get `{"player":"1","lang":"en","birthdate":"2012-12-31T00:00:00"}` That's a standard date literal that can be understood by all clients